# How to connect Smart Watch 3 to pc (WIN 7)

Tags: android, wear-os, sony-smartwatch

I bought Sony Smart Watch 3 and I don't know, how to connect to windows 7 and how to debug my created app for Android.

Thanks.

Comment: Seriously... Just check the reference. https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Bluetooth connection to debug

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html

Comment: I trying it, but it doesn't working :( I don't know why ??...But thx, I try via AVD Manager.